# Why does a VIEW with a CLUSTERED index not use the index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, materialized-view, optimization

I have a view that has a clustered index along with other non-clustered indexes.

A simple `SELECT` query does not use any of the indexes even when I select an indexed column.

What could be the reason for this?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) Enterprise Edition, on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7600)

Comment: As a minimum, you should include a sample query.  Without that, one can only guess.

Comment: Need more details. View definition, table definition, actual execution plan, when statistics were last updated on the underlying table.

Answer (score 12):

[Resolving indexes on Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181151%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> In SQL Server Enterprise, the query optimizer automatically considers the indexed view. To use an indexed view in the Standard edition or the Datacenter edition, the `NOEXPAND` table hint must be used.

I'm guessing that you're on Standard Edition.

Maybe you're falling foul of other rules listed on that page, such as:

> *The estimated cost for using the index has the lowest cost of any access mechanisms considered by the query optimizer.*

---

Like any query on a view, the reference to the view in the query is expanded into the view definition before optimization. If the optimizer finds a cheap enough way to satisfy the query before it considers matching the query tree to indexed views, you get a plan that accesses the base tables. `WITH (NOEXPAND)` is the only way to guarantee the optimizer produces a plan that accesses an index on a view directly.

Comment: In addition to the answer, it is not only limited to Enterprise edition but it applies also to developer edition.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite - technically correct, but only because Developer edition and Enterprise edition (and, I think, Evaluation edition) are all in fact exactly the same code. The only difference between them is the license.

Comment: In my case I am using Enterprise edition, but it is still not using the indexed view.  NOEXPAND did the trick, though.  My query time went down to 0 seconds with it.