# Inheritance and performance in database

Tags: sql-server, performance, materialized-view, entity-framework, hints, query-performance

I have 3 table linked by an "inheritance" with Entity Framework.
Sadly, I have poor performance with those query because I can't make any good index.
Here is the tables :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PlannedElements](
    [IdPlannedElement] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActualDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Order] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PlannedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TimeSpan] [time](7) NULL,
    [IsCompleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PlanningLineIdPlanningLine] [int] NULL,
    [AddressIdAddress] [int] NULL,
    [CrewIdCrew] [int] NULL,
    [PlannedElementIdPlannedElement] [int] NULL,
    [SuppressionDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastUpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsActualDateEstimated] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TrackerIdTracker] [int] NULL,
    [HospitalRoom] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PlannedElements] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdPlannedElement] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PlannedElements_PlannedFleetElement](
    [IdPlannedElement] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TypeOfFleetElement] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PlannedElements_PlannedFleetEl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdPlannedElement] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PlannedElements_PlannedBusinessFleetElement](
    [IdPlannedElement] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TypeOfBusinessFleetElement] [int] NOT NULL,
    [JourneyIdJourney] [int] NULL,
    [IsCertified] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PlannedElements_PlannedBusines] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdPlannedElement] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I would need an index on  JourneyIdJourney, AddressIdAddress but when I use a materialized view SQL Server is never using it;
Do you have any recommendations ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide query examples?

Comment: I think you need to post the definition of your materialized view before we can further discuss why an index is used or not..

Answer (score 1):

Paul White explains in his answer to the question below `amongst other things` that automatic indexed view matching won't even be considered if a low enough plan is found first.

[What factors go into an Indexed View's Clustered Index being selected?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/26979/what-factors-go-into-an-indexed-views-clustered-index-being-selected/27039#27039)

also
Consider [having a look at what statistics you have in each table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151136/how-to-script-statistics-in-sql-server-using-t-sql)
and [keeping them updated](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/07/rebuilding-indexes-vs-updating-statistics/)

and
[when using indexed views WITH(NOEXPAND) query hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004944/how-can-i-speed-up-this-indexed-view)

From [Query Hints (Transact SQL) on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx):

> The indexed view is not expanded only if the view is directly
>   referenced in the SELECT part of the query and WITH (NOEXPAND) or WITH
>   (NOEXPAND, INDEX( index_value [ ,...n ] ) ) is specified.